# Stretch a div to fill whitespace

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 `divs` aligned horizontally.

- Div 1 is my sidebar

  ```
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width:180px;
  height:100%;
  ```
- Div 2 is the middle (sub-content)

  ```
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  height 100%;
  ```
- Div 3 is the right part

`width:100%` on Div 3 places it below Divs 1 and 2. How can I make it stretch up the right side of the page instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use the calc() function, try the following:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
    <div class="panel">panel</div>
    <div class="main">main</div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    height: 400px;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: tan;
    float: left;
}
.panel {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: pink;    
    float: left;
}
.main {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/6qdYK/

The `overflow: auto` on `.main` will keep the div as a column without wrapping around the floated elements, which may be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because the remaining width isn't 100% but 100% is the width of full window.

So you could use css3 calc() function

```
.div3{
width: calc(100% - 180px - 200px)
}
```

See this before using calc() function [can i use calc](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Or if you want to use the width by calculating yourself define the width in pixel deducting main container width to (180+200)px.

Else, you can define the width auto which might be better for you.